# In Symfony, where to resize an image uploaded while sfValidatorFile that automatically save?

Tags: image, symfony1

In symfony 1.4, what is the best way to resize an image uploaded with a form when using **sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable** and **sfValidatorFile** and knowing that they already saved image without being asked ?

Where to put the code? I am a bit lost ...

Or should I use sfValidatorFile otherwise?

```
// In my form configure method:
$this->validatorSchema['image'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
  'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/images/',
  'mime_types' => 'web_images',
));
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it's better to put it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to do this would be overriding processValues in the form.

```
class FooForm extends BaseFooForm {

  public function processValues($values)
    if ($values['image'] instanceof sfValidatedFile) { // file was uploaded
      $temp = $values['image']->getTempName();
      // do image manipulation here using GD or other
      $values['image'] = $pathToSavedResizedFile;
    }
    return parent::processValues($values);
  }

}
```

I illustrated the same technique in an older blogpost:

http://www.gerryvandermaesen.com/posts/beyond-symfony-forms-custom-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, [this bundle](https://github.com/Gregwar/Image) defines a service, that allows manipulation both in template and in controllers